# Design principle to remove the need to redesign / modify code for all mobile platforms when update or new feature is added

Tags: android, mobile, updates, centralized

I have an issue I would like some help with.

I have a product which I want to design mobile applications for all mobile platforms.
Now while design the whole layout and architecture of the system, I need a way to try and remove the need to redevelop or change the code for every platform.

For example, if i build all my apps for, android ,windows, BlackBerry, apple etc. 
Now i release a new feature on my system, I will now have to go and update all the code for all of the mobile platforms.

Now my idea is to create a website which all the mobile devices talk to, which then talks to all of our products via the internet, This web site, centralizes all communication between the two ends.

Now the only solution to remove the needs for updates to all platforms is to then make a sort of thin client on each of the mobile devices, that then go to the website and display the websites content. Now with this, if we add a feature or fix a bug, we simply do so on the web server and in turn all of the mobile platforms will be updated already.

Now with this idea i already foresee potential problems like scaling the display for multiple clients, etc

Before I go and reinvent the wheel, I thought I would ask here if there is not already a way in which I can work around this design issue?

So basically I want to eliminate the need to make changes to all mobile platforms source code, and then publish an update which all users will have to download, and replace it with a central place of configuration where updates and changes can be made which will immediately affect all mobile platforms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You thinking in correct direction, you should not maintain multiple code for same functionality as they need to be used in multiple platform. Rather they should have a think layer for each platform talking to same set of services which would be common across all the platform. 
When you say scaling the display of multiple clients, If you have separate thin layer for each client and your complete architecture if SOA then ideally you should not have any problem. 
Happy to discuss more.

Comment: Could you care to explain more? Obviously all functionality will be on the server. But with regards to displaying functionality? I will still have to add code to each mobile app if we add a new feature so that the mobile clients can display the correct functionality?